# Running .NET Core with other .NET Frameworks and Mono Framework

Tags: .net, mono, .net-core, gtk#

I just read somewhere that it looks like the "imports" option under "frameworks" in "project.json" file let's your application use the other .NET Frameworks installed in your machine as fallback if your libraries still not yet supported in the .NET Core. If this is true, will I be able to use libraries such as GTK# through .NET 4.x with my .NET Core project? And how make my application run with Mono Framework on a non-MS Windows system?

Comment: Read that statement carefully and digest every words. Your interpretation is far from the truth.

Comment: A GTK binding is out of scope for .NETCore, it isn't core enough.  It doesn't go beyond a simple console mode app.  Look at what Xamarin is doing, they probably already have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just read somewhere that it looks like the "imports" option under "frameworks" in "project.json" file let's your application use the other .NET Frameworks installed in your machine as fallback if your libraries still not yet supported in the .NET Core.

No. `"imports"` lets your project use *libraries* that do not directly support [`netstandard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) yet. In practice, this will only work if the library already uses only the surface exposed by `netstandard`, which includes .Net Core RC1 libraries (`dnxcore50`) and libraries using some portable profiles.

> will I be able to use libraries such as GTK# through .NET 4.x with my .NET Core project?

You can use project.json/`dotnet`/.Net Core CLI to write a .Net Framework 4.x application (using e.g. `"net451"` inside `"frameworks"`), but the result is a .Net Framework application, not a .Net Core application. This is mostly useful when you're writing a library and want to have a version for .Net Core/`netstandard` and another version for .Net Framework.

> And how make my application run with Mono Framework on a non-MS Windows system?

If you're writing a .Net Core application, then you don't need mono. If you're writing a .Net Framework application using .Net Core CLI, then [mono is not supported](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3939#issuecomment-235640762), it may or may not work. If you're writing a .Net Framework application and want to run it on mono, then that works as it always did: if you're not using anything that's not supported on mono, then it should just work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.